# Is there any way to merge Brands, Regular and Solid together?

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I want to reduce requests of webpage.
font-awesome has Solid, Regular and Brands fonts. I want to merge all to one until reduce requests.

Comment: They are merged. In the package there is a file `all.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

As answered on the comments by @JakubMuda, you can use the file `all.min.js` which include all the packages you are looking for.

Just a reminder that Regular fonts are PRO. You can find more info in the following [link](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new font file, only copy the glyphs that you want to use, then create new css font. Use Fontforge to create/edit woff2 file.